# ui-grid restore() not working properly (saveState feature)

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info) latest version in an angular (1.4.8) application.
I'm trying to save the grid's state, specifically the selection and the scroll position of the grid, in order to restore it when I navigate away and back to the view containing the grid. In the state object I see the scroll position is saved.

The problem as I've isolated it is lack of renderComplete event.
I read a lot of issues and explanations regarding this by the authors - I understand that `columnDefs` and `data` can be set later on. Still, there should be some kind of renderComplete event of the **grid's data rendering**, rather than the component itself (that has no data yet).

attaching a handler to `rowsRendered` or to `rowsVisibleChanged` caused me problems and loops.
using `$scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);` helped the columns rendering, but not the scroll position.
I also defined `saveRowIdentity` and `rowEquality` methods, thought it might help but still no go.
The directive needed for the scroll feature is activated (cell-nav).

If I try to restore using a `$timeout` of 2 seconds after data was rendered - it works perfectly.

Maybe someone had the same problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sometimes with these timing issues, it works to wrap the calls in a timeout of even 0 or 1 millisecond, which is "good enough". Could you try that?

Comment: That was my first try, it didn't work well. Then I read grid.modifyRows() allows not to use $timeout(), but as I've said it helped just for some aspects like columns. The thing is that after 2 seconds it works well, which means all we need is an event for when data rendering is done.